# WSO2 4.0.0 control-plane as key manager : Error while parsing JWT - Connection refused to localhost:443

Tags: proxy, jwt, wso2, connection, localhost

**I use two WSO2 Api Manager v4.0.0 nodes inside a private network :**

- reverse is the Nginx node that proxy requests to destination ports as a gateway/entrypoint
- apim-bo is the WSO2 control-plane. It hosts devportal/publisher and is the key manager. IP 192.168.0.6, WSO2 listen on port 9443, domain apimbo.mysite.com
- apim-gw is the WSO2 gateway worker used to handle requests. IP 192.168.0.5, WSO2 listen on port 8243, domain apim.mysite.com
- I use a wildcard certificate shared between nginx and the two WSO2 nodes, same certificates and keystore files on all nodes

**It works pretty much fine but I can see a lot of errors in apim-gw logs :**

> [2023-01-16 16:19:34,010] ERROR
> {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.jwt.JWTValidatorImpl} - Error while
> parsing JWT org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to
> localhost:443 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused
> (Connection refused)  at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:156)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
> at
> org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.JWTUtil.retrieveJWKSConfiguration_aroundBody0(JWTUtil.java:58)
> at
> org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.JWTUtil.retrieveJWKSConfiguration(JWTUtil.java:52)
> at
> org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.jwt.JWTValidatorImpl.retrieveJWKSet_aroundBody22(JWTValidatorImpl.java:231)
> at
> org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.jwt.JWTValidatorImpl.retrieveJWKSet(JWTValidatorImpl.java:228)
> at
> org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.jwt.JWTValidatorImpl.validateSignature_aroundBody8(JWTValidatorImpl.java:145)
> at
> org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.jwt.JWTValidatorImpl.validateSignature(JWTValidatorImpl.java:135)
> at
> org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.jwt.JWTValidatorImpl.validateToken_aroundBody0(JWTValidatorImpl.java:62)
> at
> org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.jwt.JWTValidatorImpl.validateToken(JWTValidatorImpl.java:57)
> at
> org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.jwt.JWTValidationServiceImpl.validateJWTToken_aroundBody0(JWTValidationServiceImpl.java:44)
> at
> org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.jwt.JWTValidationServiceImpl.validateJWTToken(JWTValidationServiceImpl.java:36)
> at
> org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.jwt.JWTValidator.getJwtValidationInfo_aroundBody18(JWTValidator.java:519)
> at
> org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.jwt.JWTValidator.getJwtValidationInfo(JWTValidator.java:487)
> at
> org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.jwt.JWTValidator.authenticate_aroundBody0(JWTValidator.java:170)
> at
> org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.jwt.JWTValidator.authenticate(JWTValidator.java:138)
> at
> org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.oauth.OAuthAuthenticator.authenticate_aroundBody4(OAuthAuthenticator.java:323)
> at
> org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.oauth.OAuthAuthenticator.authenticate(OAuthAuthenticator.java:115)
> at
> org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler.isAuthenticate_aroundBody42(APIAuthenticationHandler.java:428)
> at
> org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler.isAuthenticate(APIAuthenticationHandler.java:422)
> at
> org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler.handleRequest_aroundBody36(APIAuthenticationHandler.java:353)
> at
> org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler.handleRequest(APIAuthenticationHandler.java:317)
> at org.apache.synapse.api.API.process(API.java:389)     at
> org.apache.synapse.api.AbstractApiHandler.apiProcessNonDefaultStrategy(AbstractApiHandler.java:107)
> at
> org.apache.synapse.api.AbstractApiHandler.identifyAPI(AbstractApiHandler.java:127)
> at
> org.apache.synapse.api.AbstractApiHandler.dispatchToAPI(AbstractApiHandler.java:59)
> at
> org.apache.synapse.api.rest.RestRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RestRequestHandler.java:84)
> at
> org.apache.synapse.api.rest.RestRequestHandler.process(RestRequestHandler.java:70)
> at
> org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:54)
> at
> org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:344)
> at
> org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:101)
> at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
> at
> org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:375)
> at
> org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:189)
> at
> org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) Caused by:
> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)    at
> java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)   at
> java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
> at
> java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
> at
> java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
> at
> java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
> at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591)   at
> org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:368)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)

**Do you have an idea of what I am missing please ?**

**reverse apim-bo vhost :**

```
upstream apimbo {

    server 192.168.0.6:9443;

}

server {

    # Listen
    server_name apimbo.mysite.com;
    listen      443      ssl http2;
    listen      [::]:443 ssl http2;

    # Certs
    ssl_certificate     /home/user/certs/mysite.com.fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/user/certs/mysite.com.privkey.key;

    # Proxy conf
    location / {
        proxy_pass              https://apimbo;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        Host               $http_host;
        proxy_connect_timeout   90s;
        proxy_send_timeout      90s;
        proxy_read_timeout      90s;
    }

}
```

**reverse apim-gw vhost :**

```
upstream apim {

    server 192.168.0.5:8243;
    keepalive 32;

}

server {

    # Listen
    server_name apim.mysite.com;
    listen      443      ssl http2;
    listen      [::]:443 ssl http2;

    # Certs
    ssl_certificate     /home/user/certs/mysite.com.fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/user/certs/mysite.com.privkey.key;

    # Proxy conf
    location / {
        proxy_pass              https://apim;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        Host               $http_host;
        proxy_set_header        Connection         "";
        proxy_connect_timeout   90s;
        proxy_send_timeout      90s;
        proxy_read_timeout      90s;
    }

}
```

**apim-bo /etc/hosts :**

```
127.0.1.1 apimbo.mysite.com
127.0.0.1 localhost
192.168.0.5 apim.mysite.com
```

**apim-bo deployment.toml :**

```
[server]
hostname = "apimbo.mysite.com"
base_path = "${carbon.protocol}://${carbon.host}:${carbon.management.port}"
server_role = "control-plane"

[super_admin]
username = "admin"
password = "adminpass"
create_admin_account = true

[user_store]
type = "database_unique_id"

[database.apim_db]
type = "mysql"
hostname = "192.168.0.4"
name = "apimdb"
port = "3306"
username = "apimdbuser"
password = "apimdbpass"
driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"

[database.shared_db]
type = "mysql"
hostname = "192.168.0.4"
name = "apimshareddb"
port = "3306"
username = "apimshareddbuser"
password = "apimshareddbpass"
driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"

[keystore.tls]
file_name = "wso2carbon.jks"
type = "PKCS12"
password = "wso2"
alias = "apim"
key_password = "wso2"

[keystore.primary]
file_name = "wso2carbon.jks"
type = "{{ wso2_keystore_type }}"
password = "{{ wso2_keystore_new_password }}"
alias = "{{ wso2_keystore_new_alias }}"
key_password = "{{ wso2_keystore_new_password }}"

[keystore.internal]
file_name = "wso2carbon.jks"
type = "PKCS12"
password = "{{ wso2_keystore_new_password }}"
alias = "{{ wso2_keystore_new_alias }}"
key_password = "{{ wso2_keystore_new_password }}"

[truststore]
file_name = "client-truststore.jks"
type = "PKCS12"
password = "wso2"
alias = "symmetric.key.value"
algorithm = "AES"

# Custom : apim gateway env
[[apim.gateway.environment]]
name = "Default"
type = "hybrid"
display_in_api_console = true
description = "This is a hybrid gateway that handles both production and sandbox token traffic."
show_as_token_endpoint_url = true
service_url = "https://apim.mysite.com/services/"
username= "${admin.username}"
password= "${admin.password}"
ws_endpoint = "ws://apim.mysite.com:9099"
wss_endpoint = "wss://apim.mysite.com:8099"
http_endpoint = "http://apim.mysite.com"
https_endpoint = "https://apim.mysite.com"

[apim.cache.tags]
expiry_time = "2m"

[apim.cache.jwt_claim]
enable = true

[apim.cache.gateway_token]
enable = true

[apim.cache.resource]
enable = true

[apim.cache.km_token]
enable = true

[apim.cache.scopes]
enable = true

[apim.oauth_config]
revoke_endpoint = "https://apimbo.mysite.com/oauth2/revoke"

[apim.devportal]
url = "https://apimbo.mysite.com/devportal"
api_key_alias = "apim"
display_multiple_versions = true

[apim.cors]
allow_origins = "*"
allow_methods = ["GET","PUT","POST","DELETE","PATCH","OPTIONS"]
allow_headers = ["authorization","Access-Control-Allow-Origin","Content-Type","SOAPAction", "apikey","Internal-Key"]
allow_credentials = false

[apim.workflow]
token_endpoint = "https://apimbo.mysite.com/oauth2/token"

[apim.notification]
hostname = "apimbo.mysite.com"

[[event_handler]]
name="userPostSelfRegistration"
subscriptions=["POST_ADD_USER"]

[service_provider]
sp_name_regex = "^[\\sa-zA-Z0-9._-]*$"

[database.local]
url = "jdbc:h2:./repository/database/WSO2CARBON_DB;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"

[[event_listener]]
id = "token_revocation"
type = "org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.handler.AbstractIdentityHandler"
name = "org.wso2.is.notification.ApimOauthEventInterceptor"
order = 1
[event_listener.properties]
notification_endpoint = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/internal/data/v1/notify"
username = "${admin.username}"
password = "${admin.password}"
'header.X-WSO2-KEY-MANAGER' = "default"

[transport.https.properties]
proxyPort = 443
```

**apim-gw /etc/hosts :**

```
127.0.1.1 apim.mysite.com
127.0.0.1 localhost
192.168.0.6 apimbo.mysite.com
```

**apim-gw deployment.toml :**

```
[server]
hostname = "apim.mysite.com"
server_role = "gateway-worker"

[super_admin]
username = "admin"
password = "adminpass"
create_admin_account = true

[user_store]
type = "database_unique_id"

[database.shared_db]
type = "mysql"
hostname = "192.168.0.4"
name = "apimshareddb"
port = "3306"
username = "apimshareddbname"
password = "apimshareddbpass"
driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"

[keystore.tls]
file_name = "wso2carbon.jks"
type = "PKCS12"
password = "wso2"
alias = "apim"
key_password = "wso2"

[keystore.primary]
file_name = "wso2carbon.jks"
type = "PKCS12"
password = "wso2"
alias = "apim"
key_password = "wso2"

[keystore.internal]
file_name = "wso2carbon.jks"
type = "PKCS12"
password = "wso2"
alias = "apim"
key_password = "wso2"

[truststore]
file_name = "client-truststore.jks"
type = "PKCS12"
password = "wso2"
alias = "symmetric.key.value"
algorithm = "AES"

[apim.key_manager]
service_url = "https://apimbo.mysite.com:9443${carbon.context}/services/"
username= "$ref{super_admin.username}"
password= "$ref{super_admin.password}"

[apim.jwt]
enable = true
encoding = "base64"
claim_dialect = "http://wso2.org/claims"
header = "X-JWT-Assertion"
signing_algorithm = "SHA256withRSA"

[apim.sync_runtime_artifacts.gateway]
gateway_labels = ["Default"]

[apim.throttling]
service_url = "https://apimbo.mysite.com:9443/services/"
username = "$ref{super_admin.username}"
password = "$ref{super_admin.password}"
enable_unlimited_tier = true
enable_header_based_throttling = false
enable_jwt_claim_based_throttling = false
enable_query_param_based_throttling = false
throttle_decision_endpoints = ["tcp://apimbo.mysite.com:5672","tcp://apimbo.mysite.com:5672"]

[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
traffic_manager_urls=["tcp://apimbo.mysite.com:9611"]
traffic_manager_auth_urls=["ssl://apimbo.mysite.com:9711"]

[apim.analytics]
enable = false
config_endpoint = "https://analytics-event-auth.choreo.dev/auth/v1"
auth_token = "ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff"

[apim.cache.jwt_claim]
enable = true
expiry_time = 900

[apim.cache.gateway_token]
enable = true
expiry_time = 15

[apim.cache.resource]
enable = true

[apim.cache.km_token]
enable = true

[apim.oauth_config]
remove_outbound_auth_header = true
auth_header = "Authorization"

[apim.devportal]
api_key_alias = "apim"

[apim.cors]
allow_origins = "*"
allow_methods = ["GET","PUT","POST","DELETE","PATCH","OPTIONS"]
allow_headers = ["authorization","Access-Control-Allow-Origin","Content-Type","SOAPAction", "apikey"]
allow_credentials = false

[transport.http]
properties.port = 9763
properties.proxyPort = 80

[transport.https]
properties.port = 9443
properties.proxyPort = 443

[passthru_http]
worker_thread_keepalive_sec = 60
worker_pool_queue_length = -1
core_worker_pool_size = 400
max_worker_pool_size = 400
io_buffer_size = 16384
http.socket.timeout = 180000

[message_builder]
json = "org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamBuilder"
```

Comment: Can you change the config as follows in the gw deployment.toml?

[apim.key_manager]
service_url = "https://apimbo.mysite.com/services/"

Comment: @Pubci it doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I managed to configure the control-plane as the key manager, so my errors are finally gone.

Basically the gateway tried to claim /oauth2/jwks on the gateway side instead of calling it through the control-plane. Special thanks to you @ycr you helped me a lot.

Nothing worked on deployment.toml (it looks like a bug to me), but I succeeded using the admin panel :

- Go to https://apimbo.mysite.com/admin/dashboard
- Browse the Key Managers menu
- Click on "Resident Key Manager" to edit it
- Inside "Certificates", change https://localhost:9443/oauth2/jwks to https://apimbo.mysite.com:9443/oauth2/jwks

I restarted both gw and cp to make sure that the value was not overwritten after a restart, and it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following configs to your control plane deployment.toml

If you have a single server.

```ini
[apim.key_manager]
service_url = "https://localhost:9443/services/"
username = "admin"
password = "admin"
```

If you have a HA setup

```ini
[apim.key_manager]
service_url = "https://CP_LB_HOST/services/"
username = "admin"
password = "admin"
```

**Update**

Add the following to change the JWKS endpoint.

```
[[apim.jwt.issuer]]
name = "https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token"
jwks.url = "https://CP_HOST:9443/oauth2/jwks"
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. I just did and restarted apim-bo service, but unfortunately I have the same error.

Comment: @Johnson Just realized you are seeing these in the GW node.  Which indicates the key manager configs are still pointing to localhost. As a temp workaround try removing `properties.proxyPort = 443` in the GW deployment.toml

Comment: Yes maybe... But this is weird because my clients do their call on apim-bo domain. I just tried to get tokens from apim-bo then apim-gw :
`curl -k -X POST https://apimbo.mysite.com/oauth2/token -d "grant_type=client_credentials" -H "Authorization: Basic fff"` works
and `curl -k -X POST https://apim.mysite.com/oauth2/token -d "grant_type=client_credentials" -H "Authorization: Basic fff"` returns a 404 as expected

Comment: @Johnson that behavior is correct. By default token endpoint is not deployed to the GW. Hence you have to use the CP when generating tokens. `https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token` note that oauth2 service is exposed via port 9443 and not 8243.

Comment: yes so this means the token is properly handled by cp. Maybe the issue happend when it comes to read/parse JWT tokens? I mean when the gw needs to read and validate it?
I tried to comment `properties.proxyPort = 443` on gw and now I have weird errors like `TID: [-1234] [] [2023-01-16 17:48:40,061] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.jwt.JWTValidatorImpl} - Error while parsing JWT java.text.ParseException: Invalid JSON: Unexpected token` followed by an html page saying that js is disabled on browser instead of the old one.

Comment: I think that commenting properties.proxyPort as you suggested was a good idea. If I try to request my own Api, everything is fine... But I keep getting the error I wrote in my previous comment very often. Does this message `Invalid JSON: Unexpected token <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC [...verylong...]</html> at position 16395` means that some of my clients are trying to send an html page as a token? Maybe because their token request failed before that? I try to reproduce this error myself but I can't.

Comment: @JohnsonYes,  It could be they are sending an invalid JWT. You can enable wirelogs and decode the JWT and see what's being sent.

Comment: ok thanks to you I think I'm close to succeed. I tried to enable wire logs by following [the doc](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.0.0/integrate/develop/using-wire-logs/#enabling-wire-logs) but my wso2carbon.log and other log files are still the same. I edited my log4j2.properties file by adding `logger.synapse-transport-http-wire.name = org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire
logger.synapse-transport-http-wire.level = DEBUG
logger.httpclient-wire-content.name = httpclient.wire.content
logger.httpclient-wire-content.level = DEBUG` and restarted, I can't see any difference. Any idea?

Comment: @Johnson check this https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.0.0/administer/logging-and-monitoring/logging/configuring-logging/#enabling-the-gateway-wire-logs socument

Comment: OK got it thanks. I can now see every headers and responses, and nothing looks weird. Bearer looks good. The issue is that I now only have wire logs in wso2carbon.log so I can't find problematic requests that triggers the Unexpected token...

Comment: I successfully logged both wire and error logs... There is a gap between last DEBUG and first error, as if some things were not logged. Bearer are fine.
`TID: [-1] [] [2023-01-16 21:11:09,977] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers} - http-incoming-3144 >> Authorization: Bearer XXX`
`TID: [-1] [] [2023-01-16 21:11:09,977] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers} - http-incoming-3144 >> Accept: application/json`
`TID: [-1234] [] [2023-01-16 21:11:10,016] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.jwt.JWTValidatorImpl} - Error while parsing JWT java.text.ParseException`

Comment: I just found that my gw tries to call /oauth2/jwks very often but gets a 302 to /carbon/admin/login.jsp thanks to http_access log. So I guess I have to do something to configure this endpoint properly

Comment: @Johnson You may have to change JWKS URL in that case. Check the update in the answer.

Comment: ok thanks but on which side? ^^' gw or cp?

Comment: @Johnson Gateway.

Comment: Thanks but I still have the same unexpected token error :/

Comment: I found a solution, see my answer. Thanks a lot, you helped me to understand what was happening here ;)